How to find causal inference when one subgroup of population, all are treated?
Suppose we have a dataset with different features, one of which is gender and based on the binary treatment, we observe the binary outcome (recovery). There is one issue within the dataset. Based on the data, all females are treated but only a fraction of males are treated. Now, I want to determine the individual treatment effect (ITE). However, because all females are treated, I cannot estimate the outcome when they are not treated.
I think it violates the assumptions for causal inference. I would be thankful if anybody could give me some ideas about what I should do. I think any approach results in biased estimation, but any logical approach is appreciated. I am wondering if it is possible to use ITE from males data?
I am wondering if a model like Heckman Selection Model works for this case?
Thanks

What is the treatment in question? One key assumption in causal inference is that all subjects have a probability of exposure that is neither 0 or 1.

Suppose that we are considering a medicine as the treatment. Unfortunately, in the data that I have, there is no observation where the patient is female and not treated.

I believe you’re referring to the Conditional Average Treatment Effect (CATE) rather than the Individualized Treatment Effect (ITE). The former computes the effect at the level of strata or subpopulations, while the latter focuses on effects at the unit individual level.
Violations of the positivity (or overlap) assumption, where certain covariate strata lack variation in treatment exposure, can create significant challenges for causal inference. In your case, with all females being treated, it is not possible to estimate the causal effect of treatment for this subgroup using standard methods.
Estimating the effect for the entire population is also problematic, particularly when using propensity score-based approaches. As an alternative, you could employ an instrumental variable (IV) approach, leveraging the variation introduced by the instrument, rather than the exposure itself, to estimate the causal effect.
If collecting additional data with treatment variation is not feasible, the safest approach is to limit the analysis to the subpopulation where positivity holds. For example, instead of estimating the causal effect for the entire population, focus on the subgroup of males, where treatment variation exists. The interpretation of results must be restricted to this stratum.
Another methodological alternatives could be using partial identification methods to estimate bounds for the causal effect rather than a precise point estimate.

Thank you so much. Unfortunately, I cannot collect new data or add instrumental variables. How can I find bounds for females subpopulation? Can I use results from males and use for females (although it will be biased)?

There could be many ways. For instance, If you're using a parametric model, like logistic regression, and you are willing to invoke some invariance assumptions (such as no interaction of gender with other covariates), you could justify some bounds for the relevant parameter for females using the estimated coefficient for males, and "transfer" the inference for the marginal effect (for each bound) using the females data. Yet, you need to properly justify these approach with prior theoretical knowledge and sensitivity analysis.
